# get all content between a custom tag with regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to extract all the contents of a custom tag that I created, but I try to make some form and it is not working, let's practice then:

context

```
{{#teste}}
                texto1
                {{#teste2}}
                    texto2
                {{/teste2}}
            {{/teste}}
```

I need extract all content from `{{#teste}} ... {{/teste}}`.

So far, I have arrived at the following code:

```
{{#teste}}(.|\n\s)*?{{\/teste}}
```

However, I need everything that was gitiated between and not containing itself.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/cyu3sL/1

Comment: What do you mean by `gitiated`? Do you need just `{{#teste}}((.|\n)*?){{\/teste}}`?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<={{#teste}})(?>.|\s)*?(?={{\/teste}})
```

captures everything between but excluding **{{#teste}}** and **{{/teste}}**

[Test regex](https://regex101.com/r/1ufMiv/1)